# client.guilds only works in the log and not chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

So I was adding a logging feature to my Discord.JS bot and used `console.log(client.guilds);` and it outputs the guilds and their info in the console, however, if I do `message.channel.send(client.guilds)` it sends `object Object` or `undefined` instead. So my question is how could I make my bot post the contents of `client.guilds` in the chat?

Comment: It says [object Object] because `client.guilds` (`client.guilds.cache` in V12) is a **Collection**. I wouldn't recommend sending the entire Collection in the chat, and you also need to take into account the 2000 characters limit.
[More information about Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)

Comment: I know it's not the best way but how would I go around sending the whole collection in chat?

Comment: What info do you need for each guild?

Comment: I would like the whole collection.

Comment: You can do something like:

`let data = "";
client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild=>data.concat('\n'+guild))
message.channel.send(data);`
Tell me if that works

Comment: Guild is a large object ,and discord will reject message by length limit.

Comment: Thanks, @Giuliopime, that works but as Cipher said it got rejected because of Discord's character limit.

Comment: use:
`message.channel.send(data, { split: true });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) its a large discord object with many collection. So you can`t send all data to message. But you can get some info and send it. Like this

### Discord v12

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let clientGuildsData = bot.guilds.cache.map(guild => `${guild.name} - ${guild.id}`).join('\n')
    message.channel.send(clientGuildsData)
})
```

### Discord v11

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let clientGuildsData = bot.guilds.map(guild => `${guild.name} - ${guild.id}`).join('\n')
    message.channel.send(clientGuildsData)
})
```